# Command .exe to obtain date in ISO format

Tags: cmd.exe

How can get the ISO format date placed into an environment variable regardless of regional settings? Answers to related questions here suggest this will require a special .exe, so a source of that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us). Accepted answer suggests a way to get ISO format date:

> If you want the date independently of the region day/month order, you can use "WMIC os GET LocalDateTime" as a source, since it's in ISO order:
>
> ```
> @echo off
> for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
> set ldt=%ldt:~0,4%-%ldt:~4,2%-%ldt:~6,2% %ldt:~8,2%:%ldt:~10,2%:%ldt:~12,6%
> echo Local date is [%ldt%]
> ```
>
> > C:>test.cmd
> >
> > Local date is [2012-06-19 10:23:47.048]

Comment: Thanks. That gave date and time but was easy to amend to give just date.

Answer (score -1):

Another way that will return faster than the above example because it doesn't need wmic - it uses CMD variable manipulation only is:

```
set month=%date:~3,2%
set day=%date:~0,2%
set year=%date:~6,4%
echo %year%-%month%-%day%
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I think you missed the `regardless of regional settings` part.